# tsql - how to select 6th row from 1st row and then 6th from 6th row and so on

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have table `planets` like this:

```
id  Planet Name
---------------
1   Sun     Sun
2   Moon    Mon
3   Mars    Tue
4   Mercury Wed
5   Jupiter Thu
6   Venus   Fri
7   Saturn  Sat
```

If I select 'Sun' then I want my query to return

```
Sun
Venus
Mercury
Moon
Saturn
Jupiter
Mars
Sun
Venus
Mercury
Moon
Saturn
Jupiter
Mars
Sun
Venus
Mercury
Moon
Saturn
Jupiter
Mars
Sun
Venus
Mercury
```

If I select 'Mon' then I want my query to return

```
Moon
Saturn
Jupiter
Mars
Sun
Venus
Mercury
Moon
Saturn
Jupiter
Mars
Sun
Venus
Mercury
Moon
Saturn
Jupiter
Mars
Sun
Venus
Mercury
Moon
Saturn
Jupiter
```

If I select 'Tue' then I want my query to return

```
Mars
Sun
Venus
Mercury
Moon
Saturn
Jupiter
Mars
Sun
Venus
Mercury
Moon
Saturn
Jupiter
Mars
Sun
Venus
Mercury
Moon
Saturn
Jupiter
Mars
Sun
Venus
```

If I select 'Wed' then I want my query to return

```
Mercury
Moon
Saturn
Jupiter
Mars
Sun
Venus
Mercury
Moon
Saturn
Jupiter
Mars
Sun
Venus
Mercury
Moon
Saturn
Jupiter
Mars
Sun
Venus
Mercury
Moon
Saturn
```

If I select 'Thu' then I want my query to return

```
Jupiter
Mars
Sun
Venus
Mercury
Moon
Saturn
Jupiter
Mars
Sun
Venus
Mercury
Moon
Saturn
Jupiter
Mars
Sun
Venus
Mercury
Moon
Saturn
Jupiter
Mars
Sun
```

If I select 'Fri' then I want my query to return

```
Venus
Mercury
Moon
Saturn
Jupiter
Mars
Sun
Venus
Mercury
Moon
Saturn
Jupiter
Mars
Sun
Venus
Mercury
Moon
Saturn
Jupiter
Mars
Sun
Venus
Mercury
Moon
```

If I select 'Sat' then I want my query to return

```
Saturn
Jupiter
Mars
Sun
Venus
Mercury
Moon
Saturn
Jupiter
Mars
Sun
Venus
Mercury
Moon
Saturn
Jupiter
Mars
Sun
Venus
Mercury
Moon
Saturn
Jupiter
Mars
```

Honestly I am trying to get but I am able achieve this using excel but no idea how to do it in SQL any help much appreciated

Comment: It is not clear what rules are applied to get your sequences..

Comment: Can you explain the pattern a bit, I think you just want the sequence to being with Sun or Venus depending on which one you pass in? If so I think you can just use an IF condition, and hardcode your sequence afterward.

Comment: I am trying to get that sequence based on day i.e., mon, tue wed... if I want to see order of planets for Monday then it should return the planets in the above order likewise if I choose tue to see planets then I am expecting to view that order shown in above example.  I will try with if condition. thanks

Comment: @user790049 And based on `what rules` do you determine the order? Or is it just fixed, like if you select `Moon` you get "this order"? (in this case you can hardcode it, I think it would be easier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/93762/6) that builds the sequence you are attempting to build.

The `Planets` table was slightly altered to have the Sun start at base zero because the next section reads cleaner.

```
Create Table dbo.Planets 
(
  id int not null primary key
  ,planet nvarchar(20) not null
  ,day nvarchar(3) not null  
);
Go

Insert dbo.Planets
Values
 (0,'Sun','Sun') -- (Not really a planet...)
,(1,'Moon','Mon')
,(2,'Mars','Tue')
,(3,'Mercury','Wed')
,(4,'Jupiter','Thu')
,(5,'Venus','Fri')
,(6,'Saturn','Sat');
-- (...looks like Uranus didn't make the cut.)
Go
```

The trick is to just use a [common table expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) for iteration and have an understanding of how [modulo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx) (`%`) works.

```
With PlanetSequence As
(
  Select id
    ,planet
    ,day
    ,iterations = 0
  From dbo.Planets
  Where day = 'Sun' -- Could pass in a parameter here

  Union All

  -- As the recursive section of this CTE, this is 
  -- responsible for selecting the next item in
  -- in the sequence.
  Select  Planets.id
    ,Planets.planet
    ,Planets.day
    ,iterations = PlanetSequence.iterations + 1
  From dbo.Planets
    Join PlanetSequence
    On (PlanetSequence.id + 5) % 7 = Planets.id
  Where PlanetSequence.iterations < 20
)

Select Planet From PlanetSequence
```

Result:

```
PLANET
--------
Sun
Venus
Mercury
Moon
Saturn
Jupiter
Mars
Sun
Venus
Mercury
Moon
Saturn
Jupiter
Mars
Sun
Venus
Mercury
Moon
Saturn
Jupiter
Mars
```

Comment: thanks Mike, I gave up this and created output tables in my database. But with your solution I am getting my desired output without creating table. Thanks